# Reload iframe in the background

Tags: iframe, refresh, show-hide, tableau-api

I have a webpage inside which I show a webpage(a Tableau dashboard) inside an iframe.
This iframe should refresh every 1 minute so that the dashboard can fetch updated data from the database.
However, during this refresh a blank screen/refreshing screen comes up. So I am trying to have 2 iframes with the same source and loading the alternate one with the src and swapping them.
But still I cant get the second iframe to load in the background when the first one is displaying, so I get a blank screen between each swap.
Any advice on what am mising? Thank you!
My code so far

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE, NO-STORE,MUST-REVALIDATE,MAX-AGE=0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshiframe()
{
var x=document.getElementById("xx");
var y=document.getElementById("yy");
if(x.style.display=="none"){
y.style.display="none";
x.style.display="block";
$('#myframe2').attr('src',"http://localhost/views/mypage1?:embed=y&:toolbar=no&:display_count=no&:refresh=y");
}
else{
x.style.display="none";
y.style.display="block";
$('#myframe').attr('src',"http://localhost/views/mypage1?:embed=y&:toolbar=no&:display_count=no&:refresh=y");
}
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#xx{
display:block;
}
#yy{
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval(refreshiframe,60000);">
<div id="xx"><iframe id="myframe" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" src=http://localhost/views/mypage1?:embed=y&:toolbar=no&:display_count=no width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
</iframe></div>
<div id="yy"><iframe id="myframe2" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" src=http://localhost/views/mypage1?:embed=y&:toolbar=no&:display_count=no width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
</iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no any reason for a hidden frame loads and keep freshring

Comment: I dont want to see the refreshing screen symbol and white flash, thats y I want to hide it and refresh then show it